# I got a bounty I didn't deserve -- why?

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

Recently, I received an automatic bounty for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861826/file-is-visible-on-my-desktop-but-not-via-the-ls-command) on AskUbuntu, but there's no way I could have deserved the award.

As per the help center:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

This just doesn't line up with what happened. Another answer was higher-voted and was posted earlier than mine, yet I still got the bounty. Why did this happen, and is it possible to fix this issue and give the bounty to the right person?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answer was posted *before* the bounty was placed, and therefore it doesn't qualify to receive the bounty (at least not *automatically* - the user who placed the bounty could have awarded the bounty to one of the other answers but needed to do so *actively*). Your answer was actually the *only* one qualifying for the bounty.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Kind of... strange, but I guess I'll take it?

Comment: So . . . the bounty amount awarded by the system will go only to those answers that were posted within bounty's 7 days period , is that what you're saying ?

Comment: @Serg yes, that's right. It's all explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) but it's a rather long text.